# Как сделать запись в бд?

Tags: python, бот

Пишу бота на python. При старте в бд заносятся id, firstname, lastname, username. В дальнейшем юзер может отправить номер телефона. Вопрос: как добавить по id? Или лучше сделать отдельную таблицу с id и номером и туда заносить?

Answer (score 0):

Сразу создай таблицу с колонками: id, firstname, lastname, username, telephone(по дефолту NULL), и когда юзер пришлёт тебе номер просто запиши его туда.

Пример:

```
from peewee import *


class BaseModel(Model):
    class Meta:
        database = None  # Тут твоё подключение к БД


class User(BaseModel):
    id = PrimaryKeyField(primary_key=True, unique=True)
    firstname = CharField()
    lastname = CharField()
    username = CharField(unique=True)
    telephone = IntegerField(null=True, default=None)


# Создание нового пользователя:
user = User.create(firstname='Имя', lastname='Фамилия', username='Никнейм')

# Допустим он прислал номер
user.telephone = 00000000000
user.save()
user.update()
```

Советую сразу юзать ОRM так как они очень упрощают жизнь и ускоряют разработку.

Comment: спасибо, а если он номер отправляет через кнопку?

Comment: А разница? Ты просто получи этот номер, а как это вопрос к тому как устроен твой бот. Я не совсем понял что значит "через кнопку"